# how to make a conditional ajax call triggered by onbeforeload based on a variable's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script uses "onbeforeunload", ajax, and logout.php (which updates mysql with a loggedin status of 1 or 0) to give a "live" status of users login. This way if the user closes their tab or hopefully also if they close their browser(untested) mysql will be able to track their login status whereas if I were monitoring cookies they would still be shown as logged in with their active session.

Problem is this makes every page refresh or href link clicked log me out.

I tried to solve this by adding an if statement to the ajax called by the onbeforeunload. This would execute the ajax logout if a variable say "var unload==true". My header.php script is on all site pages and I added var unload=true; to it.(To reset my ajax triggered by onbeforeunload on every page load)

For my links I tried using onclick to "turn off" ajax logout by setting unload=false.
It should have then been "turned on" again with the header.php's code var unload=true since it is on every page.

Now it is turned off and the onbeforeunload isn't triggering the ajax logout with F5 refresh or closing tab as it should.

Is the if statement not recognizing the variables? Is their a better way to go about this? As always I really appreciate your insight and help. Thank you.

Below is the applicable code.(I attempted with localstorage variables. No luck...)

header.php:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("unload","true");

window.onbeforeunload = function() { 

 if(localStorage.getItem('unload')=="true"){
 $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type:"POST",
        url: "/WIP/secure_login/logout.php",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(resp){
        window.alert("you should be logged out now.");

           }

    });
}
};
document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link").addEventListener("click", 
function(){
localStorage.setItem("unload","false");
};
</script>
```

demo.php

```
<?php
include '../header.php';
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
localStorage.setItem("unload","false");

  $.ajax({
        async:true,
        type:"POST",
        url: "../header.php",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(result){
            location.reload();
        }   
    });
});
localStorage.setItem("unload","true");
</script>
```

Comment: I get, the purpose of all this is to track who is actively "loggedIn" and who isn't? I.e. Who is actually on the site in real-time?

Comment: Yes,  Can you think of any reasons why why the onbeforeunload if statement doesn't seem to be functioning as was hoped?

Comment: Yes, many reasons... Please see my answer for a real world approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The expectation is to determine who is actively "loggedIn" and who isn't.** Your current approach is misguided. You can achieve your goal as follows:

## I would do something like this:

*First-*
Create a new page, call it something like `pulse.php`. This php file will be responsible for querying the *Users* table for the $currentUser and updating a timestamp (e.g.: `updated_at`) and possibly setting a boolean column (e.g.: `active`) to true. This is optional and depends on what your User model schema is.

*Next-*
Add the following javascript to your header.php:

```
const getPulse = () => $.get("/pulse.php");
setInterval(getPulse, 300000); // This fn will be fired every 5 minutes
```

*Finally-*
Setup a scheduled task (i.e. cron job) to run say every 5 minutes on your server. This task will be responsible for querying the Users table where `USER.updated_at time is longer than 5 minutes from NOW() AND USER.active = true`. *Any results returned from this query will be Users which are no longer actively online (i.e. closed their browser tab). You can now update those User records accordingly.*

Comment: A very viable solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I can't seem to get the time field (mysl time format) to update using time() (php function). It simply displays one time and doesn't update each time the query is called.